# Want a SQL to group values by value scope in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table t1 and there is a column named days, so I want to group the days by 1 to 5 days and 6-15 days and more than 15 days then calculate the count for each group, but I don't know how to write the sql, can anyone tell me? the result should be looked like below:

```
Number  Scope(days)    
  5      1-5
  7      6-15
  10     15+
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have no idea at all

Answer (score 4):

If I understand well, this could be a way:

```
with t1(days) as ( 
    select  1 from dual union all
    select  2 from dual union all
    select  5 from dual union all
    select  6 from dual union all
    select  7 from dual union all
    select  8 from dual union all
    select 10 from dual union all
    select 11 from dual union all
    select 16 from dual union all
    select 17 from dual union all
    select 19 from dual union all
    select 19 from dual
)
/* the query */
select count(*),
       case
        when days between 1 and  5 then '1-5'
        when days between 6 and 15 then '6-15'
        else '+15'
       end    
from t1
group by case
        when days between 1 and  5 then '1-5'
        when days between 6 and 15 then '6-15'
        else '+15'
       end
```

that gives:

```
  COUNT(*) CASE
---------- ----
         3 1-5
         4 +15
         5 6-15
```

The idea is to aggregate by something that say the "group" where every number is, and you can easily build such an information with a `CASE`.

Accordin to Jarlh's suggestion, this can be re-written as

```
select count(*), the_group
from (
        select case
                when days between 1 and  5 then '1-5'
                when days between 6 and 15 then '6-15'
                else '+15'
               end the_group
        from t1
     )     
group by the_group
```

This obviously assumes that you only have positive numbers.

Comment: With a derived table you don't have to repeat the `case` expression in the `GROUP BY`! (And also become ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Great! (Much less error-prone, and easier to maintain.)